# Обычный счетчик

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку генерируется число и записывается в textView. Когда число становится слишком большим, скажем так 2.000.000.000, то он ставит перед ним знак минуса и число постоянно вычитается. Т.е. теперь так же генерирует число, но не складывает, а вычитает. В чем проблема?

Код нажатой кнопки

```
case R.id.s70000x100000:
            watchCount = watchCount + r.nextInt(20000000) + 30000000;
            watchUsers.setText("Просмотров на канале - " + watchCount);
            dialogContract.cancel();
            break;
```

Здесь показано, как он меняет знак на минус и просто вычитает большое накопленное число и сгенерированное число

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте использовать `long`

Comment: скорее всего это происходит из-за переполнения

Answer (score 4):

Максимальное число в INT 2147483647, у Вас случается переполнение и из-за этого получается такое число. Используйте long и метод nextLong.

Comment: Есть тип  `long `  и тип `int`, никакого типа `long int` в Java нет

Comment: Извиняюсь, немного ошибся, исправил) Спасибо

Comment: Ещё есть BigInteger